# Changing numeration and headline in document

Tags: documentclass

I write my thesis using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\noindent\textbf{\huge Incoming Records Classificatio gdhjkdfhlfgdfldgslfgdfldhfjhfgklhdfslhfgfdhsjhgflfgjlfsdghfgsd}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}
```

However, I get the title in which there is no space between lines.
In addition, each new section starts with `0.` as can be seen in following: [image][image]

Comment: I suggest you insert the instruction `\par` immediately after `gdhjkdfhlfgdfldgslfgdfldhfjhfgklhdfslhfgfdhsjhgflfgjlfsdghfgsd`. (Aside: I'm assuming [hoping?!] that you don't plan on typesetting `gdhjkdfhlfgdfldgslfgdfldhfjhfgklhdfslhfgfdhsjhgflfgjlfsdghfgsd` in your real document...)

Comment: Regarding the numbering: You might want to use `\chapter` instead of `\section` or alternatively, use the `article` documentclass instead of `report`. Regarding the title, you might also be interested in `\title{...}` and the `\maketitle`  command.